# Can "I have not" be used as an answer to "Do you have chicken for lunch?"

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

> Q: Do you have chicken for lunch?

If I want to answer this question I can say

> no, I don't

or

> I have not

Answer (score 1):

You can use this reply if you are *accused* of having eaten the chicken.

"There was chicken in the kitchen that I wanted for supper. It's gone, I bet you have eaten it". "I have not". Here we don't have a question, but a statement was made, and another statement to counter it. If a question is asked, then the reply is "No, I didn't".

Answer (score 0):

You should say, "No, I do not" or "No, I don't".

You are implying: "No, I do not [have chicken for lunch]".

This does not make any sense: <strike>"I have not chicken for lunch"</strike>

As a general rule of thumb, to answer a question, move the subject before the predicate. Then you can remove everything after the verb and change "you" to "I". For example, "Do you have chicken for lunch?" becomes "**You do** have chicken for lunch" and then just "I do/don't."

Answer (score 0):

Do you (usually/habitually) have chicken for lunch?

Yes, I do.
No, I don’t.

Do you have chicken for lunch? (currently in your lunch bag, for example)

Yes, I do.

No, I don’t. 
No, I haven’t. (British)

Comment: In the UK *Haven't* is the negative response to *Have you?*. We would respond negatively to *Do you?* with *Don't* same as anywhere else? We would only say *No, I haven't* in response to *Have you got chicken for lunch?*